# Extra type checking in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there any opportunity to set advanced type checking to see an error in next example:

```
type Id = number;

const id: Id = 1;
const notId: number = 2;

function test(val: Id) {
  console.log('val', val);
}

test(id)
test(notId)
```

Comment: TypeScript is _structurally_, not nominally, typed. `type Id = number` is really just making an alias. The way around this is sometimes referred to as _"branded types"_.

Comment: It looks more like a hack but as I understood there is no other way